# gcc feature: generate list of source files from binary

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb, objdump

Does **gcc** having feature which can **list of source files (.c/.c++/.h)** from binary (if binary is having debug information)..??

I know same be can be achieved through **objdump** and **GDB** too.
But "objdump" and "GDB" give the list of only ".c" file.

For Exapmle:
I have two file (test.c and test.h) and i have compiled test code with "-g" option and used "objdump" as below:

```
bdk4user@llvm:~/home$ objdump --dwarf=decodedline a.out 

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Decoded dump of debug contents of section .debug_line:

CU: test.c:
File name                            Line number    Starting address
test.c                                         4            0x40057d
test.c                                         6            0x400585 
test.c                                         7            0x40058f
test.c                                         8            0x4005a1
...
```

But it doesn't list the ".h" file which is also used.

So my question is, does **GCC** having any **feature** which can give list of all file which are being used in binary.??

OR any other utility to achieved the same..??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like an XY question ("I want to do X, I think Y is the right solution, so I ask how to do Y"). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: When you compile the program, pass option -E, and look at the lines starting with `#` in the output. Any other place in the toolchain is too late.

Comment: @ Mats Petersson: I just want to know whether **gcc** also hold the feature of **listing the source file from binary**. sorry i could not convey in proper way.

Comment: @AnshuSharma As mentioned gcc isn't used to inspect binaries.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥε: Thank you for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 1):

> *"But it doesn't list the ".h" file which is also used."*

Since header files are processed with the C/C++ preprocessor, even before the `.o` files are generated, none of these tools can have a notion of them.

Comment: The preprocessor introduces (proprietary) indications of the origin of each line, that is used for warnings and also stored in the debug information. If there is actual code in the .h, the OP's command will list it.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ for quick reply. so mean to say "No tool" can give ".h" files information.Does **gcc**' give the list of source file as **objdump** gives..??

Comment: @Marc Glisse : Thank you for reply. i did not get you "If there is actual code in the .h, the OP's command will list it"..? What is **OP's** command.?

Comment: @AnshuSharma _"What is OP's command.?"_ What you wrote in your question: `objdump --dwarf=decodedline a.out `

Comment: OP = "Original Post(er)" - OP's comand = "Command posted in the original post".

Comment: Sorry i couldn't understand (Now understood OP's mean). 
@Marc Glisse: i have  defined  **#define** in "test.h" file which is being used in "test.c" file, then it should list "test.h" file too. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Does **gcc** give the list of source file as **objdump** gives..?? Kindly share your experience on it..

Comment: @AnshuSharma _"i have defined #define"_ As mentioned, nothing that is handled by the preprocessor, will be seen in this list, despite it appears as inlined code.

Comment: @AnshuSharma "actual code" means there is a function definition. Macros are the close to invisible.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: Understood, Thanks. how about **gcc** ..? does it list source file..if yes..please post the command..

Comment: @Marc Glisse: Thank you correcting me. **gcc** hold this feature. ??

Comment: @AnshuSharma gcc is used to compile the source. It's possible to let it generate a list of header file dependencies, while the compilation is done (see `-MM` et al options).

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: Thanks for info.will check the same